# Tcl: Unable to read variables of 32 bit registry hierarchy on a 64 bit machine

Tags: tcl

Using Tcl 8.4

While trying to query registry keys for 32 bit registry hierarchy ona 64 bit machine with following command:

(user) 9 % registry keys {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall} *

It retrieves keys from the hierarchy HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall instead of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Tried executing from system32 command line:

```
(gjoshi) 11 % {c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe} {REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall}
```

But found the following result

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
C:\Users\gjoshi>Not enough storage is available to process this command.
```

On running the same command from a manually launched shell of c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe via Windows Explorer it returned the correct registry entries.

So i tried to create a batch file for this command but when the batch file was run on tcl it still gave the registry entries from 32 bit registries only.

The main intent over here is to get a value for particular key - uninstallString in our application stored under the uninstall hierarchy with the name of its GUID instead of the application name. We need this to trigger un-installation of the application build installed.

Kindly advise if I could search the 32 bit registry hierarchy or any other way to find the uninstall string or to trigger the un-installation of the application manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... following does the trick

```
tcl\> set str [REG QUERY {HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall} /s /reg:64]
```

This returns 32 bit registries in a 64 bit machine (though the notation sounds weird but it works).

Next is to bring out the install string which can be done as follows:

```
tcl\> foreach {x y} \
        [regexp -inline -all -nocase {\n(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.*?)\nHKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE} $str] {
          if [regexp -nocase MY_APP_NAME_OR_SOME_MATCHING_STRING $y] {
             puts [lindex [regexp -inline {(UninstallString[^\n]*)} $y] 1]
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

The low-level registry libraries in Windows try to match up what view of the registry you get with the build of the program calling it. This means that 32-bit binaries can't normally see 64-bit keys and *vice versa*.

There is a workaround, but it requires that you upgrade to Tcl 8.6 since that supports an optional mode switch to dictate which view of the registry you're getting, e.g.:

```
registry -64bit keys
```

The fix hasn't been backported to 8.5 (not sufficient user demand) and *will not* be backported to 8.4 as that's been end-of-lifed and is now unsupported. Upgrade.

Comment: Is there anyway a batch code written in shell-script could be executed from Tcl to bring back the 32 bit registry hierarchy